# flask many to many join as done by prefetch_related from django

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have following Group and Contact model in flask with Sql Alchemy ORM

```
group_contact = db.Table(
    'group_contact',
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'group.id')),
    db.Column('contact_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'contact.id')),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('group_id', 'contact_id')
)


class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))


class Contact(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    groups = db.relationship(
        "Group", secondary=group_contact, backref='contacts')
```

Now I need to query Contact with groups:

```
contacts = Contact.query.join(Group, Contact.groups).all()
for contact in contacts:
    print(contact.groups)
```

Here the problem is number of SQL query increases as number of contact increases when I execute above code.

Django ORM has prefetch_related() with queryset which does the following according to django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related.

Now I am trying to do the same thing with Sql Alchemy by the following code:

```
contacts = Contact.query.all()     
contact_groups = group_contact.query.join(
    Group
).filter(group_contact.contact_id.in_([item.id for item in contacts]))
```

But this gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'query'
```

How can I get prefetch_related like feature from django with SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to tell SQLAlchemy to eagerly load related objects by using a [relationship loading technique](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html). SQLAlchemy can be told to load the groups together with the contacts in a single query.

For just this one query, you can add [`joinedload()` option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) (it is available via the Flask-SQLAlchemy `db` object):

```
contacts = Contact.query.options(db.joinedload(Contact.groups)).all()
```

This pre-loads the `Contact.groups` attribute on each matched contact:

```
for contact in contacts:
    # no new query issued to fetch groups, the data for the groups
    # is already available
    print(contact.groups)
```

The query executed looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    contact.id AS contact_id,
    contact.phone AS contact_phone,
    group_1.id AS group_1_id,
    group_1.name AS group_1_name
FROM contact 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    group_contact AS group_contact_1
    JOIN "group" AS group_1 ON group_1.id = group_contact_1.group_id
) ON contact.id = group_contact_1.contact_id
```

You can also set a default loading strategy for the relationship on the model; to always eagerly load groups, use `lazy='joined'` on the relationship:

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    # ...
    groups = db.relationship(
        "Group", secondary=group_contact, backref='contacts',
        lazy='joined')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful.