# Many to many query in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There are tables for my question.

```
class TemplateExtra(ExtraBase, InsertMixin, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'template_extra'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    roles = relationship(
        'RecipientRoleExtra',
        secondary='template_to_role',
    )


class RecipientRoleExtra(
    ExtraBase, InsertMixin, TimestampMixin,
    SelectMixin, UpdateMixin,
):
    __tablename__ = 'recipient_role'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class TemplateToRecipientRoleExtra(ExtraBase, InsertMixin, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'template_to_role'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    template_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('template_extra.id'))
    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipient_role.id'))
```

I want to select all templates with prefetched roles in two sql-queries like Django ORM does with prefetch_related. Can I do it?
This is my current attempt.

```
def test_custom():
    # creating engine with echo=True
    s = DBSession()

    for t in s.query(TemplateExtra).join(RecipientRoleExtra, TemplateExtra.roles).all():
        print(f'id = {t.id}')
        for r in t.roles:
            print(f'-- {r.name}')
```

But..

1. it generates select query for every template to select its roles. Can I make sqlalchemy to do only one query?
2. generated queries for roles are without join, just `FROM recipient_role, template_to_role` with `WHERE %(param_1)s = template_to_role.template_id AND recipient_role.id = template_to_role.role_id`. Is it correct?

Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer:
[flask many to many join as done by prefetch_related from django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054787/flask-many-to-many-join-as-done-by-prefetch-related-from-django)

Maybe somthing like this:

`roles = TemplateExtra.query.options(db.joinedload(TemplateExtra.roles)).all`

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Came to the same result after extra research. Accept your answer.
SQLAlchemy docs are awful :) All my previous attempts to figure out the right way of querying end up with nothing.